# Always place second

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me with a logic. Suppose I've 3 cards one above another. I want to write a logic where when user clicks on the card its position should change to second card from 3 always. That means if it is on the top it should go to second position. If on bottom should go to second position. If on second position already nothing should happen. Please help using javascript(preferably). Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
$('.close1').unbind('click').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.pop').each(function (key, value) {
        $(this).css('z-index', (key + 1) * 2);
    });
    if ($(this).parent().attr('data-z-index') == 1) {
        $(this).parent().css('z-index', 5);
    } else {
        $(this).parent().css('z-index', 3);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like homework.

Comment: looks like the start of a three card monte app :p

Comment: I've tried the code below but the problem is the last card if on second position never comes on the top.$('.close1').unbind('click').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.pop').each(function (key, value) {
            $(this).css('z-index', (key + 1) * 2);
        });
        if ($(this).parent().attr('data-z-index') == 1) {
            $(this).parent().css('z-index', 5);
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().css('z-index', 3);
        }
    });

Comment: @user3368953 you can only click on the top card at all times right?

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle maybe?!

Comment: Yes can u please check this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/50qg9gcf/1/). This is what I've made till now. But the only problem with this is suppose Orange card is at second position. Then if the top card is clicked it should come to the first position. But it goes to last. Sorry forgot to mention click on the minimize button on top right. :)

Comment: @user3368953 any reason why my answer doesn't suit you?

Comment: It's nothing like that...i don't know how to use swap. Can u please modify the fiddle to implement the same.:)

Comment: I hope you can use it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took this as a little challenge and decided to do it from scratch. Here is a working demo.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ypor986t/2/)

**code:**

*html*

```
<div id="container">
    <div data-pos="0" class="card" id="c1">card 1</div>
    <div data-pos="1" class="card" id="c2">card 2</div>
    <div data-pos="2" class="card" id="c3">card 3</div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
#c1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#c2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#c3 {
    background-color: green;
}
.card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

*Javascript*

```
var position = [{
    left: 100,
    top: 100
}, //if zindex = 0
{
    left: 110,
    top: 110
}, //if zindex = 1
{
    left: 120,
    top: 120
} // if zindex = 2
];

var $container = $('#container');
//initial set up
(function () {
    $('.card').each(function (index, value) {
        var $value = $(value);
        var z = $value.data('pos');
        $value.css('z-index', z);
        $value.offset(position[z]);
    });
})()
var switchHandler = function ($cardA, $cardB) {
    var z1 = $cardA.css('z-index');
    var z2 = $cardB.css('z-index');
    $cardA.attr('data-pos', z2);
    $cardA.css('z-index', z2);
    $cardB.attr('data-pos', z1);
    $cardB.css('z-index', z1);
    $cardA.offset(position[z2]);
    $cardB.offset(position[z1]);
}

$('.card').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        z = $this.css('z-index');
    switch (true) {
        case z == 0 || z == 2:
            switchHandler($this, $container.find('[data-pos="1"]'));
            break;
        case z == 1:
            console.log('Position two.. not doing anything');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('An error occured');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Grimbode....it helped alot and its working as expected....Thanks everyone:)

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you. ^^

Comment: Sorry i forgot....Done:)